# How to print text from UIWebView to JavaScript form?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, forms, uiwebview

I'm trying to populate a UIWebView with a website. I want the app to show a nicer log in view than the website itself. Therefore, I have a UIWebView in the background. I'm trying to fill the form on the website with the text fields I have created in the view controller but my code won't work.

Here's the form on the website:

```
<div class="centerloginform">

<form name="userForm" action="Login.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" class="hidden" id="action" value="login" />
  <div class="loginheader">Logga in</div>

  <div class="login_formtable">
    <label class="login_label">Jag är</label>
    <div id="loginselect" style="clear:both:">
      <select name="usertype" size="1"  id="usertype" class="select1" >   
        <option value="0"  selected="selected">Personal</option>
        <option value="1" >Elev</option>
        <option value="2" >Vårdnadshavare</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <label class="login_label">Användarnamn</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" name="ssusername" size="20" maxlength="50" />
    <label class="login_label">Lösenord</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="sspassword" size="20" maxlength="20" value=""/>

    <div><input type="submit" name="button" value="Logga in"  class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <center>
```

And here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {


    NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('ssusername') ssusername.value='%@';", _username.text];

    NSString *loadPasswordJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('sspassword')[0]; sspassword.value='%@';", _password.text];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary');"];

}
```

Can anyone help me so that the text the user writes in the text field of the app is printed in the form on the website? I suspect there's something wrong with my Java `getElementsBy` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one JS call:

```
NSString *submitFormJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"document.getElementsByName('ssusername')[0].value='%@';"
                          "document.getElementsByName('sspassword')[0].value='%@';"
                          "document.getElementsByName('userForm')[0].submit();",
                          _username.text, _password.text];
```

P.S. it's a good idea, to change *'name='* attribute in HTML code with *'id='* and access elements like

```
document.getElementById('ssusername').value = 'smth';
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but when I type in the textField username.text nothing appears in the form on the website. I have the UIwebView in the background with alpha set to low so I can see if anything happens. Is there anything else that can be wrong?